# How to query sqlite database where date ends in 12 days?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a problem with one SQLiteDatabase query.
I want to show user things where date ends in 12 days. It looks like:
`@Query("SELECT ID, NAME_PRODUCT, AMOUNT, DATE_EXP FROM Table WHERE date_exp not null AND date_exp <= DATE('now', '+12 days') ORDER BY date_exp ASC")`
But it prints me date that are later in the range of for example **(18-06 to 20-06) 21-06** is not printed. I expect elements where date end max in **12-06** from today. So where is the problem?
Also I want to show elements where date **has already ended**. So how can I do that?
I will only add that I store data as **String**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Issue**

> I will only add that I store data as String.

You appear to be using dates in a format that is not directly sortable or comparable using greater than/less than type expressions. And especially cannot be compared directly against `date('now',...)`.

e.g. **18-06** is greater than **01-07** as the day is the higher priority (1 is greater than 0).

Furthermore, `date('now','+12 days')` would on 01-07-2021 return/resolve to **2021-07-13** so 18-?? (of any month) would only be less than dates less than or equal to **1799-12-31**. (due to any numeric character (**0** .... **9**) being greater than **-**)

**Fix 1 (store data in a friendlier format)**

One solution, and what would be recommended, would be to store the data in YYYY-MM-DD format. Then your comparisons would work and also the date and time functions would also work (such as `strftime` as used below and also `date` as you have used)

- See the link at the end for date/time formats and in-built functions

If dates in this format were used then you could use (your query) :-

```
@Query("SELECT ID, NAME_PRODUCT, AMOUNT, DATE_EXP FROM Table WHERE date_exp not null AND date_exp <= DATE('now', '+12 days') ORDER BY date_exp ASC")
```

**Fix 2 (handle the unfriendly format)**

Another option, not recommended (as you may well to experience similar issues), would be, assuming just the DD-MM format (wouldn't cater for years) would be to use `substr(date_exp,4,2)||'-'||substr(date_exp,1,2)` to transform the DD-MM format to MM-DD and to use either `substr(date('now','+12 days'),6,5)` or `strftime('%m-%d','now','+12 days')`.

So the following could be used:-

```
@Query("SELECT ID, NAME_PRODUCT, AMOUNT, DATE_EXP FROM `Table` WHERE date_exp not null AND substr(date_exp,4,2)||'-'||substr(date_exp,1,2) <= substr(date('now','+12 days'),6,5) ORDER BY substr(date_exp,4,2)||'-'||substr(date_exp,1,2) ASC")
```

**Working example/demo in native SQLite**

The following SQL :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name_product TEXT, amount REAL, date_exp TEXT, other_date_exp TEXT);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
    (null,'blah',25.12,'18-06','2021-06-18') /* XXX Should not be in result */
    ,(null,'blah',25.12,'18-06','2022-06-18') /* XXX Should not be in result */
    ,(null,'blah',25.12,'18-05','2021-05-18') /* Should be in result */
    ,(null,'blah',25.12,null,null) /* XXX Should not be in result */
    ,(null,'blah',25.12,'19-05','2021-05-19') /* Should be in result */
    ,(null,'blah',25.12,'20-05','2021-05-20') /* Should be in result */
;

SELECT ID, NAME_PRODUCT, AMOUNT, DATE_EXP FROM `Table` WHERE date_exp not null AND date_exp <= DATE('now', '+12 days') ORDER BY date_exp ASC;
SELECT ID, NAME_PRODUCT, AMOUNT, other_date_exp FROM `Table` WHERE other_date_exp not null AND other_date_exp <= DATE('now', '+12 days') ORDER BY other_date_exp ASC;
SELECT ID, NAME_PRODUCT, AMOUNT, DATE_EXP FROM `Table` WHERE date_exp not null AND substr(date_exp,4,2)||'-'||substr(date_exp,1,2) <= substr(date('now','+12 days'),6,5) ORDER BY substr(date_exp,4,2)||'-'||substr(date_exp,1,2) ASC;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
```

1. Drops and creates the text table (note Room encloses names (e.g. table and columns) in `` (a table named table would result in a syntax error as it's a keyword))
2. inserts rows for testing
3. runs your original selects
4. runs the two solution selects (recommended first)
5. cleans up the environment

The first query results in  what you are experiencing:-

[image]

The second and third queries result in what you are expecting (albeit the 2nd with the additional column using the suggested format that SQLite can handle) :-

[image]

and

[image]

You may wish to refer to https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

- Tested using Navicat for SQLite.